Source of aphorism "To do many things is to do nothing well"
At some point in my life I heard the saying "To do many things is to do nothing well." I thought that it was an Ancient Greek aphorism, but searching for its source, I can't find it at all. Did my brain pull this quote out of thin air?

There's a similar aphorism in English; Jack of all trades, master of none, although  Wikipedia says that the second half of the expression was added later.

Henry Ford is alleged to have said "If you try to do everything, you will do nothing well.”. I can't find a source for it though.
